# Prepopulate Visualforce InputText - Force.com Site

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites, urlhacking

How do you pre-populate an inputText field on a Visualforce page? This is for a force.com site.

I understand the controller portion. However, why can I not brute force populate the input field with "Cheese".

There is an id of "name" assigned to the inputText.

Url:

```
http://testpets.force.com/petname/petname_1?name=Cheese
```

Visualforce:

```
<td><apex:inputText value="{!Pet__c.Name__c}" size="50" maxlength="50" styleClass="inputtext" label="Body" id="name"/> </td>
```

Comment: Yes. I have tested this behavior few months back. the only solution I found is using controller to populate the value.

Comment: The only clear and safe solution for pre-populating fields is an apex controller.

Comment: @sfdcweb Thank you, I am going to write a controller for this. I wish I could just force it.